# PHP: Plot Data Points From MySQL on Graph (Google Graphs)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, graph

I'm trying to query our database to get all records that match the user defined query, and store the data in a formatted array. The problem is, I'm getting all of the records, but not really sure how to process the data appropriately. I've been working on this for a few days now and haven't made much head way after trying a variety of ideas. Hopefully, someone here will have some insight to share.

The code below executes the query and starts processing the returned data into the array:

```
    $msg_vol = array();
    $xy_coords = array();
    $tweet_count = 1;

    $query = "SELECT created_at, tweet_id FROM `tweets` WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%{$safe_q}%' AND created_at < now() - 300";
    $tweets = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    confirm_query($tweets);

    while ($tweet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tweets)) {
        $created_at = $tweet['created_at'];
        $timestamp = strtotime($created_at);
        $created_at_no_seconds = date('Y-m-d H:i', $timestamp);

        if(!in_array($created_at_no_seconds, $xy_coords)) {
        $created_at = $tweet['created_at'];
        $timestamp = strtotime($created_at);
        $created_at_no_seconds = date('Y-m-d H:i', $timestamp);

        if(!in_array($created_at_no_seconds, $xy_coords)) {
            $xy_coords = array(0 => $created_at_no_seconds, array('tweet_count' => $tweet_count, 'retweets' => 0));
        } else {
            // $created_at_no_seconds exists in array
            // update array
            $msg_vol[$created_at_no_seconds] = array('tweet_count' => $tweet_count++, 'retweets' => 0);
        }
    }
    return $msg_vol;
```

I'm reformatting the $created_at to the minute as, for the time being, I'm only interested in the data for the last 5 minutes (300 seconds) and want each minute separated out into it's own associative array. The $created_at_no_seconds variable can potentially contain duplicate entries to be added in the array. So, I've toyed with in_array() to try and check if it exists and only add it to the array if it does not. I didn't have much luck with this yet.

A print_r($msg_vol) provides the following output (which is slowly getting closer to the desired output):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2013-12-15 19:09
        [tweet_count] => 1
        [retweets] => 0
    )

[2013-12-15 19:09] => Array
    (
        [tweet_count] => 11
        [retweets] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2013-12-15 19:09
        [tweet_count] => 1
        [retweets] => 0
...
[12] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2013-12-15 19:10
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tweet_count] => 12
                [retweets] => 0
            )

    )

[2013-12-15 19:10] => Array
    (
        [tweet_count] => 20
        [retweets] => 0
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2013-12-15 19:10
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tweet_count] => 12
                [retweets] => 0
            )

    )
...
```

(I'm not processing the retweets at the moment, so I'm simply adding a 0 to the retweets array as a placeholder).

I'm trying to format it so that in one array, it contains the unique date (down to the minute) where the values for tweet_count is stored within it. The above example with the date as the associative key, and the $k => $v inside is what I'm trying to achieve. But, when I keep getting the array populated with [0], [1]. [12], [13], etc.

Am I even close? This has been quite the rabbit hole... And, it's starting to become a dark and lonely place. :(

Answer (score 0):

instead of using array push like this

```
array_push($msg_vol, $xy_coords);
```

why not try

```
$array[] = $xy_coords;
```

With regards the duplicates why not use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your mysql query?

Comment: I ended up  changing from array_push to $msg_vol[] = $xy_coords and am getting the same result. So, that's good and also a little more clear. As far as the SELECT DISTINCT, I'm not sure how I can implement that since multiple rows will have the same created_at date, and I still need the rows that match the rest of the query. Maybe I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: i maybe misunderstanding too. Which field needs to be unique?

Comment: I updated the code to what it currently looks like and tried to further clarify it. The Y-m-d H:i should be one unique array index, with the $k => $v being the array attributes. So, in the above code, the array element [2013-12-15 19:09] => Array is correct, but the others are superfluous and I'm not sure how to weed them out.

Comment: so if a date doesn't exist are you not wanting this value included?

Comment: No, I still want the value included if the date doesn't exist... I'm still working on ironing that part out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by optimizing the query (Thank you #php)!

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i'),";
    $query .= " COUNT(tweet_id), 0 FROM `tweets`";
    $query .= " WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%{$safe_q}%'" ;
    $query .= " AND created_at < now() - 300"; 
    $query .= " GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i')";
    $tweets = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    confirm_query($tweets);

    while ($tweet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tweets)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($tweet); exit;
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Make use of MySQL functions. They are a life (and, hair) saver!